# File download not working in Safari?

Tags: angularjs, safari

I have developed an angular JS web application with PDF file download functionality. It doesn't work in Safari.

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: common.serviceUrl(config.apiServices.usermanuals),
        params: { manualId: manualId },
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        headers = headers();
        //var test = headers('Content-Disposition');
        var filename = headers['x-filename'];
        var contentType = headers['content-type'];

        var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
        try {
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
            linkElement.setAttribute("download", filename);

            var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
                "view": window,
                "bubbles": true,
                "cancelable": false
            });
            linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    }).error(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Please help me find a workaround to this. Thank you

Comment: _"It doesn't work properly in Safari"_ What does that mean?

Comment: @zeroflagL question modified

Comment: You only removed a word but still didn't explain what you mean. Do you get any errors?

Comment: '[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Blob([data], { type: contentType })')

Answer (score 0):

Try using [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

```
var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf;charset=utf-8' });
FileSaver.saveAs(file, filename);
```

***data** is coming from api response,

***filename** you can pass as `abc.pdf`